# Google Maps - Remove Polyline not working

Tags: android, google-maps

So, to remove polylines that I've added I know that I need to call polyline.remove(). The problem is that it isn't working.

I've tried setting up the following code, to figure out whether it might be my logic that was at fault.

```
public class RouteFinder {
    private GoogleMap _googleMap;

    private Polyline _lastRoute;

    ...

    public void displayRoute(String result) {

        ...

        PolylineOptions line = new PolylineOptions();
        line.color(Color.parseColor("#e5007d"));
        line.width(3);

        JSONObject startLocation = legs.getJSONObject("start_location");
        line.add(new LatLng(startLocation.getDouble("lat"),startLocation.getDouble("lng")));

        for(int i = 0; i < steps.length(); i++){
            JSONObject step = steps.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject end = step.getJSONObject("end_location");
            line.add(new LatLng(end.getDouble("lat"),end.getDouble("lng")));
        }

        //Add line to map
        _lastRoute = _googleMap.addPolyline(line);
        _lastRoute.remove();
    }

    ...
}
```

So I'm removing the line just after adding it. But it still shows up on the map. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don´t know much about the maps android API, but in Javascript you can access the path array and say _lastRoute.setPath(null) / or insert empty array

Comment: Try using handler.postDelayed() in your test code in order to remove it a few seconds after adding it.

Comment: @DanielNugent No dice. Path is still there.

Comment: Strange... Have you tested on multiple devices?